# Having trouble using str(count) in Python

Tags: python

Hey I'm trying to write a script to scrape a website of information of new products. I've already gotten super far but when I run it it says

```
print str(count)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm incredibly new to Python and this is giving me headaches. Here is my full code:

```
import requests

session=requests.session()

headers={
    ':host':'launches.endclothing.com',
    'accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip,deflate',
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'
}

for count in range(50):
    try:
        itemUrl='https://launches.endclothing.com/api/products/'+str(count)
        itemRes=session.get(itemUrl,headers=headers)
        print str(count)
        print itemRes.json()['name']+' : '+itemRes.json()['colour']
        print itemRes.json()['releaseDate']
        print '\n'
    except:
        print 'N/A'
        print '\n'
```

Comment: My crystal ball says you're using Python 3. `print()` is a function in Python 3.

Comment: I suspect Frederic is correct

Comment: Yep, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using python 2.7 and your code works just fine. No error.

As @ Frédéric Hamidi stated , if you are using python 3.x

replace `print str(count)` with print `(str(count))` and try.

Answer (score 2):

if you are  using python 3  then you have to write code like this.

```
print (str(count))
```

Comment: Just a side note: In Python 2.7 this syntax will work too.